# Using AND operator with multiple elements in xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

In my XML file I want to pull all records where both indictator="3" and status="Test". This XPath query works when I use indicator="3" and indicator="2" for example but when I use it with 2 different elements it doesn't work.

```
/*[local-name()='Sample']/*[local-name()='Pageview']/*[ self::Indicator=3 and self::Status="Test"  ]

<Sample>
<Pageview>
<Indicator>3</Indicator>
<Status>Test</Status>
</Pageview>
<Pageview>
<Indicator>3</Indicator>
<Status>Test</Status>
</Pageview>
<Pageview>
<Indicator>2</Indicator>
<Status>Non-Test</Status>
</Pageview>
</Sample>
```

Comment: What elements do you want the XPath to return? `Pageview`/`Status`/`Indicator`, something else?

Comment: In addition to the answer from @har07, it seems odd to test Pageview and Status only for the local name, and to test Status and Indicator for the full (expanded) name. Either you want to match the elements regardless of namespace, or you don't.

Answer (score 0):

This bit doesn't make sense to me :

```
/*[self::Indicator=3 and self::Status="Test"]
```

an element can't be `Indicator` element as well as `Status` element at the same time, let alone taking the element value into consideration.

If you want to return either `Indicator` or `Status` element having certain value, then the condition should have been `or` instead of `and` :

```
/*[self::Indicator=3 or self::Status="Test"]
```

If you want to check if the parent element has both children elements at the same time, then you want to try this XPath :

```
/*[local-name()='Sample']/*[local-name()='Pageview'][Indicator=3 and Status="Test"]
```

If none of the above helped you, please clarify the question with what you want the XPath to return *exactly*. As an aside, I can't see why you have to use `local-name()` for some elements in your XPath, you should've used proper namespace prefixes if possible.